# Getting error - [Token line number = 1, Token line offset = 21, Token in eror =- ]

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I am new to visual basic database I am connecting to database using `.sdf` 
i am getting the following error in `visual studio 2010` when i run this function.

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1, Token
>   line offset = 21, Token in eror =-]

Can any one please tell how to fix this error.

```
Private Sub Save_Record()

    Dim con As SqlCeConnection = New SqlCeConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCeCommand
    Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty


    con.ConnectionString = Get_Constring()
    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Try

        If Me.txtFirstName.Tag = 0 Then
            sSQL = "INSERT INTO patients-2015 ( first_name, last_name, gender, phone_number, age, address, height, standing_bp, heart_rate, notes, reffered, disease, sub_diseases, registered_date, updated_date, prescribed_medicines)"
            sSQL = sSQL & "  VALUES ( @first_name, @last_name, @gender, @phone_number, @age, @address, @height, @standing_bp, @heart_rate, @notes, @reffered, @disease, @sub_diseases, @registered_date, @updated_date, @prescribed_medicines)"
            cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        Else
            sSQL = "UPDATE patients-2015 SET first_name = @first_name, last_name = @last_name, gender = @gender, phone_number = @phone_number, age = @age, address = @address , height = @height, standing_bp = @standing_bp, heart_rate = @heart_rate, notes = @notes, reffered = @reffered, disease = @disease, sub_diseases = @sub_diseases, registered_date = @registered_date, standing_bp = @standing_bp, prescribed_medicines = @prescribed_medicines WHERE id = @id"
            cmd.CommandText = sSQL
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter With {.DbType = DbType.UInt64, .ParameterName = "@id"}).Value = Me.txtFirstName.Tag
        End If

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@first_name"}).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtFirstName.Text)) > 0, Me.txtFirstName.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@last_name"}).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtLastName.Text)) > 0, Me.txtLastName.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@gender"}).Value = IIf(Not Me.ComboGender.Text = "Select", Me.ComboGender.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@phone_number"}).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.TextPhoneNumber.Text)) > 0, Me.TextPhoneNumber.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@age"}).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtAge.Text)) > 0, Me.txtAge.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@address"}).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtAddress.Text)) > 0, Me.txtAddress.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@height"}).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtHeight.Text)) > 0, Me.txtHeight.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@standing_bp"}).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtBp.Text)) > 0, Me.txtBp.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@heart_rate"}).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtHeartRate.Text)) > 0, Me.txtHeartRate.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@notes"}).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtNotes.Text)) > 0, Me.txtNotes.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@reffered"}).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtRefferer.Text)) > 0, Me.txtRefferer.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@disease"}).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.ComboDisease.Text)) > 0, Me.ComboDisease.Text, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@sub_diseases"}).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.CheckedList_SubTopic.SelectedItems.ToString)) > 0, Me.CheckedList_SubTopic.SelectedItems.ToString, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter With {.DbType = DbType.DateTime, .ParameterName = "@registered_date"}).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(DateAndTime.Now.ToLongTimeString)) > 0, DateAndTime.Now.ToLongTimeString, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter With {.DbType = DbType.DateTime, .ParameterName = "@updated_date"}).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(DateAndTime.Now)) > 0, DateAndTime.Now, DBNull.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@prescribed_medicines"}).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtPrescribedMedicines.Text)) > 0, Me.txtPrescribedMedicines.Text, DBNull.Value)


        ' Dim Result As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        Dim Result As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

        'If the record is new then we have to get its ID so that we can edit it rightaway after the insertion.
        If Me.txtFirstName.Tag = 0 Then
            cmd.CommandText = "Select @@Identity"
            'Set textbox tag property with the ID of new record
            Me.txtFirstName.Tag = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        End If

        If Result <> 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Insert failed.")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Data has been saved.")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Update code lines with `[patients-2015]` where you have written table name. For example below,

```
 sSQL = "INSERT INTO [patients-2015] ( first_name, last_name, gender, phone_number, age, address, height, standing_bp, heart_rate, notes, reffered, disease, sub_diseases, registered_date, updated_date, prescribed_medicines)"
```

So you need to apply this change - everywhere in the code where you have written table name without `[ ]`.

Hope this will solve your error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! #SOReadyToHelp BTW - if you upvote my post you will get a Bronze 'Supporter' badge for your first upvote.